# Django - Session variables does not change unless the page is refreshed

Tags: python, django, session, session-variables

I am using a session variable to check whether the user is logged in as a **contractor** or an **employer**

When contractor :

```
request.session['LoggedAsContractor'] = True
```

When employer :

```
request.session['LoggedAsContractor'] = False
```

I then implemented two switch methods, toContractor & toEmployer, that simply changes the session variable.

From the HTML view, when I click the switch button, the variable does not change and nothing else changes, but when I refresh the page, the variable changes and everything else.

**This error does not happen when running the project on the localhost, it only happens when the project is deployed (Gondor).**

This is the type of session I have :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.sessions',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
)
```

**UPDATE**

This is the method **toContractor** which is called by the button **Switch**

```
def switchToContractor(request, user_name):
    request.session['LoggedAsContractor'] = True
    if "employer" in request.GET['next']:
        if str(request.user) == user_name:
            return redirect('/contractor/' + user_name + '/')
        else:
            return redirect(request.GET['next'])
    else:
        return redirect(request.GET['next'])
```

The difference between **request.session['LoggedAsContractor'] = True** and **request.session['LoggedAsContractor'] = False**, is the view in the HTML.

**The HTML code :**

```
{% if request.session.LoggedAsContractor %}
    <!-- Show some buttons -->
{% else %}
    <!-- Show other buttons -->
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is the HTML code that contains the Switch button :

```
{% if request.session.LoggedAsContractor %}
    <a href="/contractor/{{request.user}}/switch/?next={{request.path}}">Switch to Employer View</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="/employer/{{request.user}}/switch/?next={{request.path}}">Switch to Contractor View</a>
{% endif %}
```

the url **/contractor/username/switch/** redirects to the method **switchToEmployer**.

the url **/employer/username/switch/** redirects to the method **switchToContractor**.

Comment: What is the "switch button"? What does it do? Are you sure it's calling the relevant function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redirecting, you should instead render a response with the updated session. For example:

```
def my_example(request):    
    request.session['key'] = True
    response = render_to_response("example.html", context_instance = RequestContext( request ), mimetype = "text/html" )
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error any request needs a response to display something to the user. Can you add your button function?