# Cached data prevents update in django template

Tags: python, django, session, caching, memcached

I'm working with django session [using cached session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions) configuration. My session object holds a value which when updated doesn't get reflected on my webpage until i use browser's hard refresh.

*`any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated ( actually my first time working with session and cache directly )`*

> **A Quick Analogy:**
>
> Before update **count = 0** and after update **count = 1**
>
> count value is saved on django's session object
>
> `request.session['counter'] = count`
>
> **The problem**
>
> instead of having **1** displayed on my template (HTML), i get **0** instead. This is true unless i do a hard refresh on my browser ( `Cntrl + r` ) which will only update current page, but every other pages will hold previous value of count which is **0**

**MY CODE**

View which handles update

```py
def increment_quantity(request):
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    item_id = int(request.POST.get('item_id'))
    item = get_object_or_404(Product, id=item_id)

    if quantity < 1:
        quantity = 1
    item.quantity = quantity
    item.save()

    if request.session.get('product_present', False):
        # if a product is present
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=int(request.session['product_id']))
        request.session['product_count'] = product.get_total_item()

    products = get_all_products(request)
    return redirect('product:product_list')
```

**Stack Overflow's solution that i've tried**

[link one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147600/django-session-cache-not-updated-when-using-cookie-based-session-storage)

[link two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776523/django-session-variables-does-not-change-unless-the-page-is-refreshed)

**What i've tried personally**

I've tried using middleware that get called for each request and response chain. On this middleware i  set session object to what ever count value is at the time of request/response.

**The code**

```
class ProductMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.session.get('product_present', False):
             # if a product is present
             product = Product.objects.get(pk=int(request.session['product_id']))
             request.session['product_count'] = product.get_total_item()

        request.session.modified = True
        return self.get_response(request)
```

And this is my middleware setup on `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    .....
    .....

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'product.middleware.CartMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
     
    .....
    .....
]
```

I've got the custom middle before `UpdateCacheMiddleware` and `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` ( my thought being that if session object changes, then when UpdateCacheMiddleware is called, it should notice the changes and then updates itself, which will in turn makes `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` retrieve the updated cache version) in request and response chain, but still - problem persist.

**Help Please**

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove from my middleware

```
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
```

With that done, i need not refresh my browser anymore to get my updated value to be seen.
**Thanks to @BBQ in django discord server**

Comment: I am facing the same problem as well ig, but where do we add out custom middleware in the list? I use per-site caching with database backend, new writes or post, get, put, patch, delete does not update the cached data